# Sonata Admin - A2LiX Translation Field + Sonata Formatter Type

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, a2lix-translation

I've plugged [Formatter](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/2-2/doc/index.html) (with CKeditor) to the `'content'` field in one of my Sonata's `Admin` classes. This `'content'` also has a translation, that's editable through `'a2lix_translations_gedmo'` translations type. I've been trying to add CKeditor to this field as well, but it throws exceptions in any configuration I'm trying to set.

Google knows nothing about it, as well as SO. I've also looked in [Sonata News Bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle) sources (where `sonata_formatter_type` is implemented), but there are no translations available.

My Formatter field:

```
->add('content', 'sonata_formatter_type', [
    'label'                => "Content",
    'event_dispatcher'     => $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher(),
    'format_field'         => 'contentFormatter',
    'source_field'         => 'rawContent',
    'ckeditor_context'     => 'my_config',
    'source_field_options' => [
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'span10', 'rows' => 10
        ]
    ],
    'listener'             => TRUE,
    'target_field'         => 'content'
])
```

My Translation fields:

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', [
    'label' => "Управление локализациями",
    'translatable_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article',
    'fields' => [
        'content' => [
            'locale_options' => [
                'ru' => [
                    'label' => 'Контент'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

Maybe someone knows how to add `'sonata_formatter_type'` to this damn `'a2lix_translations_gedmo'` type (or `'a2lix_translations'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'a2lix_translations_gedmo' or 'a2lix_translations' depends of the translation strategy chosen.
Gedmo strategy is discouraged and you shoud use a more recent translation strategy like the KnpLabs that I recommend. https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable

Othewise, see  https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle/issues/177#issuecomment-94949480

Comment: Yes, solution from GitHub works just fine. Thank you! I think I'll use KNP bundle in my next project, thanks for pointing it out as well. Cheers!